# what is wrong with my binary search python code

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

I am constantly getting the wrong output in my binary search program.
The output is always None even when the key element is present. Have a look at my code and help, please.

```
guess=1
def binary_search(n,key):
    low=0
    high=len(n)-1
    
    while(low <= high):
        mid=(low+high)//2
        guess=n[mid]
        if(guess==key):
            return mid
        elif (guess<key):
            high=mid-1
        elif(guess>key):
            low=mid+1
    return None

n=[1,3,5,7,9]
print(binary_search(n,3))
```

Comment: @Old_Arrack not true: `return mid`

Comment: @2e0byo Oh yeah, I'm really sorry I didn't see it.

Comment: I literally opened an answer to type exactly the same thing...

Answer (score 4):

Your search conditions are wrong. if `guess>key` then you need to decrease the guess my setting `high=mid-1` and increase the guess with `low=mid+1` if `guess<key`.

```
guess=1
def binary_search(n,key):
    low=0
    high=len(n)-1
    
    while(low <= high):
        mid=(low+high)//2
        guess=n[mid]
        if(guess==key):
            return mid
        elif (guess>key):
            high=mid-1
        elif(guess<key):
            low=mid+1
    return None

n=[1,3,5,7,9]
print(binary_search(n,3))
```

Comment: In other words, they need to swap ``+`` and ``-`` or ``<`` and ``>``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that wouldnt work. setting `high=mid+1` doesnt make sense.
`if key < mid` then `high = mid - 1`  else `low = mid+1`.

Comment: So the second case, they need to swap the ``<`` and ``>``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes